Are pagan gods possessed by demon? How can Jesus help with influence from pagan hindu deities?
I have a background involving the worship of Ganesha, the Hindu elephant-headed deity, and I’ve recently begun exploring Christianity. Since this transition, I’ve faced troubling experiences and feelings of torment by this pagan deity, especially on days significant to Ganesha like tuesdays or 4th day after full moon or new moon, leading to deep depression and frustration.
While I believe in Jesus, my family continues to honor Ganesha, complicating my situation. I feel that the influences of this pagan god are affecting my life and mental well-being.
My questions are: Can Jesus deliver individuals from the torment of pagan gods like Ganesha? Additionally, can Jesus deliver these pagan gods themselves from any spiritual influences

If possible, it sounds like you should seek help from a pastor you trust. This site can't do that, but some study of Romans might be helpful.

This is not a question about 'Christianity', Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site.

Like any library, Christianity Stack Exchange offers great information, but does not offer personalized advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your pastor, priest, or other trustworthy counselor.

There may be an acceptable Question here, though I don't understand what is written enough to be sure what it is. In any case, to be acceptable to this SE, the personal aspects should be toned down or (ideally) removed.

Welcome to the site, Phil. I note you say "I believe in Jesus," but apart from that tiny sentence everything is about a particular Hindu deity (Ganesha) and you now being deeply depressed, and your heart being filled with hatred. This site could close your Q down as inappropriate for answers about Christianity, as you have not asked a Q about that. Your Q 'Can Jesus deliver pagan gods from demons?' indicates real misunderstanding about Christ and pagan gods. As it stands, this Q liable to be stopped. Do edit your Q and remove all the personal details.

Hello @Anne thank you for replying. I have rephrased the question. Please advise.

That is certainly an improvement, Phil. Having to shut down right now, but hopefully I can attempt an answer tomorrow morning. Just wait and see if others feel able to contribute information in the meantime.

Neither death, nor life, nor nakedness, nor the sword, nor anything in earth [I quote from memory] can separate us from the love of God [Romans 8]. Ganesh isn't a being and can't hurt you (OT references to foreign gods). Even if he were, Jesus is more powerful.

@Wyrsa, it's true that, as Christians, we believe Hindu "gods", if they exist at all, are themselves demons. However, as that is not the OP's understanding as of writing, please don't alter the question to distort the OP's understanding. (Also, we discourage changing Questions that already have Answers when the change would distort what is being Answered.)

The Bible very clearly proclaims that there is just one God.  It also very clearly proclaims that there are powers and principalities, angels and demonic spirits, and things that exalt themselves against the knowledge of Christ. The Bible sometimes references these as gods.
Therefore Christianity would say that, though Ganesha is worshiped as a pagan God, it actually is no such thing for there is only one God.
Ganesha might be merely the concoction of the human mind or it might be some entity desiring the worship that belongs to God alone.  Both of these options exalt themselves against the knowledge of the one true God.
All power in heaven and on earth has been given to the Lord Jesus Christ.  Put all weight of trust on Him;  He can be trusted to deliver.

Recently beginning to explore Christianity, and adding that you "believe in Jesus", by no means evidences having become a Christian. If, as the question puts it, you are seeking Jesus' help with influence from pagan deities, that motivation - in itself - will not likely result in a better outcome. There is only one basis for turning to Christ so that he will save, and that is confess you are a sinner who cannot save oneself, putting faith in what Jesus did via the cross and his resurrection to deliver from "the wages of sin and death" (Do read the first 8 chapters of the New Testament book of Romans.)
The need is not to explore demonic influences, but to discover who Jesus Christ really is; his pre-human existence with God as the everlasting Word of God (John chapters 1 to 3), becoming flesh as the virgin Mary's child, ministering to sinners to the death, being raised triumphantly from the grave, and interceding before God for sinners. Also, that he is to suddenly appear in glory to deliver his people and to judge all evil. On that basis, Christians have supreme trust in Christ, who does, indeed, deliver them from evil.
The entire Bible warns of millennia of demonic influences that keep bringing God's people down, when they ignore his warnings to flee idolatry. In the Old Testament, his people (Israel) just kept returning to worship of pagan deities, even after God heard their prayers for deliverance from them. God told them not to even have the names of those false gods on their lips. Humanity is drawn by a magnetic pull from invisible, demonic forces. The last book of the Bible warns that demons are working to draw the nations into the last conflict against God and Christ. Only Christ can smash demonic influences / attacks when a sinner sincerely repents, in abhorrence at their own sin, and flees to Christ alone. Until that has happened (and when it does, the person knows it by the work of the Holy Spirit in them) nothing can stop demonic torments.
This means that the answer offered to the question is, tinkering around the edges of this matter avails nothing. Only total surrender, in faith, to Christ, will change anything. To do that, a person has to immerse themselves in crying out to God for understanding of who Christ, the Saviour, is, that one may be forgiven and belong to him alone, by faith.

Introduction: To a Hindu, all avatars (incarnations of gods) are mythical and non-historical. But Jesus is an historical person who lived and died in a specific time and place, and historians confirm this. Christ is a unique person of history, indeed the creator God Himself, who came to settle the sin problem of humanity. His resurrection is the proof that He was indeed God in human form.
This article explains how Jesus is unique from Hindu avatars because Jesus was a real person who lived, died and was resurrected:

Some Hindus consider Jesus as an avatar and, more specifically, as the reincarnation of Krishna. However, Jesus was not reincarnated; He was resurrected. Jesus was not an avatar; He is fully human and fully God.


Jesus is the only path to eternal salvation. In John 14:6, Jesus said, “I am the way and the truth and the life. No one comes to the Father except through me.” This coming to the Father is accomplished via belief (John 3:18) and repentance (Luke 13:3). The consequences of unbelief are harsh and eternal (Revelation 21:8). First Thessalonians 1:9-10 tells us to turn “from idols to serve the living and true God, and to wait for his Son from heaven, whom he raised from the dead—Jesus, who rescues us from the coming wrath.”

Are pagan gods possessed by demons? There are many false gods and goddesses, idols made up of bits of wood or stone or metal. They are not real. They do not exist, except in the minds of people who worship what has been created rather than worship the creator. Behind every pagan god or goddess are demons, who are real, and who represent the forces of evil, darkness and death. All demons are enemies of the one and only true God, the creator of all life and light.
Can Jesus deliver individuals from the torment of pagan gods like Ganesha?  Yes.  He delivered many people from demon possession when he came from heaven to dwell for a short time on earth.  But before a person can be delivered from the demonic forces behind pagan gods and goddesses, they must renounce such false worship and repent, turning in faith to Christ Jesus, believing in who he is – the Son of God.
Can Jesus deliver these pagan gods themselves from any spiritual influences?  Pagan gods and goddesses are not real. They do not exist, but demons absolutely do exist in the spiritual realms.
When Jesus was here on earth, the demons, who believe there is only one God, shuddered (James 2:19) because they know their eternal punishment awaits. The demons are enemies of God and have aligned themselves with the powers of darkness and death. They don’t want to submit to God’s authority and rule.
Your challenge is to find out who Christ Jesus really is and turn in faith to Him.


Can Jesus deliver individuals from the torment of pagan gods like Ganesha?

First, as others have noted, within Christianity there is only one true God, the Father (1 Cor 8:6). Others maybe addressed as if God (like the angel in the burning bush in Exodus 3, or even a man like Moses in Exodus 7) on account of the fact that they are sent as God's representatives and act on his behalf - but they are not truly God Almighty himself.
The bible also makes many references to the various gods that other surrounding nations worshiped - like Baal. However, never are these foreign gods acknowledged as anything real. Rather, scripture mocks people for worshiping the idols that they make with their own hands.
That said, the scriptures do acknowledge evil / unclean spirits that torment people. The Gospel of Mark in particular makes many references to Christ casting out daemons. Perhaps the most famous instance being the casting out of Legion into the herd of pigs, which in turn drowned in the sea. So most certainly, through prayer and faithfulness, God can empower people to overcome such unclean spirits.
That said, I would not jump to the conclusion that you are being tormented by an unclean spirit. Rather, there is no doubt a lot of internal conflict between your new way of life and your old - especially when, as you say, you are still surrounded by the regular worship of Ganesha on account of your family and friends. Such a change cannot be easy. I would encourage you to try to find a local Christian group that can provide support in such trying times. Not only can a priest provide counseling, but by incorporating more fellow believers into your daily life it may help you in your journey and your new way of life.

Additionally, can Jesus deliver these pagan gods themselves from any
spiritual influences

If such pagan gods are hypothetically actual spiritual entities / demons / etc. then I see no reason why Jesus could not help them if they sought his help. Scripture declares that even we will judge the angels. But, as with us, they will surely be judged on their own actions. No amount of prayers can force them to change their ways - that desire for change must come from themselves, of their own volition.
Again, however, the scriptures never acknowledge any such gods as real. They are treated as nought but idols that man has created for himself to worship.

I'm going to answer this. You deserve an answer.

Yes, God does deliver those from the influences of demonic forces. This is seen repeatedly in the Bible. However at no point does Jesus imply that this is an easy task.

The best advice I can give, is to seek out your priest and tell him about it. So that the church can care for you properly. If your church priest does not care... seek out another priest. Demonic dreams are a serious test... it could be all in your mind, or it could be something worse.
If you are of the Orthodox Christian denomination, the priest should respond appropriately. The Divine mystery of holy unction might be appropriate here... I'm not a priest and exorcism prayers are always a weird subject.
I cannot stress this enough, your priest should respond, he should help you.

Mind your own business. The salvation of demons is not our concern. They do not want to be saved.


Metropolitan Kallistos Ware tells the story of a four-hour car journey he once had with a Greek arch­­bishop. Hoping to enjoy a long conver­sation on the topic, he asked the archbishop: “If it is possible that the devil, who must surely be a very lonely and unhappy person, may eventu­ally repent and be saved, why do we never pray for him?” The hierarch peremp­torily replied, “Mind your own business.” End of discussion.
Ware comments: He was right. So far as we humans are concerned, the devil is always our adversary; we should not enter into any kind of negotiations with him, whether by praying for him or in other ways. His salvation is quite simply none of our business. But the devil has also his own relationship with God, as we learn from the prologue of the book of Job, when Satan makes his appearance in the heavenly court among the other “sons of God” (Job 1:6-2:7). We are, however, altogether ignorant of the precise nature of this relationship, and it is futile to pry into it. Yet, even though it is not for us to pray for the devil, we have no right to assume that he is totally and irrevocably excluded from the scope of God’s mercy.


My first impression and opinion is that this is just your psychological emotional response due to the new change of religion, resulting in frustration and hatred to this previous god. I have heard that some Maharastrians Christians have a tendency to characterise Hindu Gods as demons, and even certain Biblical evil or bad creatures. I want to advise against such fearful and superstitious beliefs. In reality, they are just idols, they are useless. Even if you eat their communion prasad offered to idols, it is harmless. The fear is just psychological, comparable to the guilt faced by people committing adultery, because you might be subconsciously feeling you're betraying the old god. You should also consider whether the evangelist you have been listening to giving you a fleshly, emotional message or a spiritual message of wisdom. It could be the case of carnal preachers or apologists that preach a mental message that scares you about your pagan gods; if so, then you need to leave the company of such preachers, otherwise they will instigate unnecessary hatred and strife in your life with your family and even your mental and spiritual health.
You should study the Paul's epistles that talk about eating animals sacrificed to idols, and having weak conscience. When your conscience becomes stronger as you grow in maturity, you will overcome this frustration and anxiety. I hope you also don't start hating your friends and family due to this conversion, but develop peace and harmony with everyone. There are people who spend their lives as covert Christians among Muslim nations, while praying the Salat in their mosques with everyone, to avoid suspicion and due to fear of life; the same is applicable for Christians among Hindus. The idols cannot harm Christians, neither the black magic, even if you're surrounded by them.
It in case that it is a spiritual attack due to pagan gods or the demons, you just need to pray to Jesus for help, and he will guide and deliver you from all troubles. I have seen testimonies on YouTube and on Jesus Redeems ministry, that in some cases, the newly converted family suffers diseases and troubles after not getting rid of the idols, and then they threw out all idols then they were delivered completely. However, you have no such certainty that they are causing this, nor you have the authority to rid the idols. If something is serious and spiritual, then there is no doubt about it, but your case is likely to be psychological. Prayers, and baptism should solve it easily.

According to the Bible, pagan gods not only aren't gods; they are powerless things that can't do anything at all, much less hurt you. Psalms 115:4-8:

They have mouths, but do not speak; eyes, but do not see. They have ears, but do not hear; noses, but do not smell. They have hands, but do not feel; feet, but do not walk.

Jeremiah 10:3-5 is more pointed:

A tree from the forest is cut down and worked with an axe by the hands of a craftsman. They decorate it with silver and gold; they fasten it with hammer and nails so that it cannot move. Their idols are like scarecrows in a cucumber field, and they cannot speak; they have to be carried, for they cannot walk. Do not be afraid of them, for they cannot do evil, neither is it in them to do good.

Habbakuk 2:18-19 also ridicules the idea of a pagan god doing anything:

What profit is an idol when its maker has shaped it, a metal image, a teacher of lies? For its maker trusts in his own creation when he makes speechless idols! Woe to him who says to a wooden thing, 'Awake'; to a silent stone, 'Arise!' Can this teach? Behold, it is overlaid with gold and silver, and there is no breath at all in it.

1 Cor 8 has this:

So then, about eating food sacrificed to idols: We know that 'An idol is nothing at all in the world' and that 'There is no God but one.'

1 Cor 10 does say the gods are demons:

Do I mean then that food sacrificed to an idol is anything, or that an idol is anything? No, but the sacrifices of pagans are offered to demons, not to God, and I do not want you to be participants with demons.

...but even that doesn't grant them any actual ability to do anything.
Ganesha is art -- wood and metal and craftsmanship. He can't hurt you. Most of the verses here suggest he's not even a conscious being.
Europeans used to have those pagan gods too, but demoted them to mere stories. Now it would never occur to most of us to worship them or even believe their existence. Maybe you'll be happy if you take the same attitude toward Ganesha.
